# Web app with Vue.js 2 and Firebase stopped working properly

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuejs2

I had a web app hosted on my personal server. It was built with Vue.js 2 and it was working properly until last month that I checked.

Basically, it loaded some content from Firebase and after choosing some options in the app, it gave me a result.

Even if I try to display some text that is not from Firebase, it still refuses to show anything.

In the console, there are no errors, but the only message I noticed was this:

> ["add",{"textareas":[],"contenteditables":[],"iframes":[],"htmlghosts":[]}]
>   bundle.js:8321:29

I'm not sure what it is. I don't know what is suddenly wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: any snippet example?

Comment: We need more info, post your code or try to get us more errors.